# What is the Instant Client MACOSX default username/password

Tags: macos, sqlplus, instantclient

I have installed SQL Plus and Instantclient on MacOSX and I have been trying to connect to the server using the given client, however, all the default password combinations I am trying aren't working. If someone uses it, can you please share the default username/password?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "default password for SQLPlus". Neither SQLPlus nor the instanclient store any passwords. SQLPlus sends the password you enter to the Oracle server you are connecting to - the server then validates your password. You need to ask the DBA of the **Oracle server** you are connecting to to give you the correct username and password.

Comment: For some background info about usernames and passwords see https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-users-grant-them-privileges-and-remove-them-in-oracle-database and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDJacg0NuLow

Comment: I figured out a way on how to use Instantclient to connect to a remote server now. However, I would like to ask if there is any way to run an independent Oracle server on OSX itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you start SQL Plus, the user and pass asked are the credentials to connect to a database, for a remote connection, you can do with the following command:

```
sqlplus 'user_name@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dns_name)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=database_name)))'
```